# python error with apply function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have the sample data and code below where I'm trying to loop through the dataDF column and find the first case of 3 increasing values and then return the Quarter value corresponding the the 3rd increasing value from the dataDF column.  I'm getting the error below and I'm not sure why.  I'm really new to python so any tips are welcome.

Sample Data:

```
 return dataDF.head(20).to_dict() 

{'Quarter': {246: '2008q3',
 247: '2008q4',
 248: '2009q1',
 249: '2009q2',
 250: '2009q3',
 251: '2009q4',
 252: '2010q1',
 253: '2010q2',
 254: '2010q3',
 255: '2010q4',
 256: '2011q1',
 257: '2011q2',
 258: '2011q3',
 259: '2011q4',
 260: '2012q1',
 261: '2012q2',
 262: '2012q3',
 263: '2012q4',
 264: '2013q1',
 265: '2013q2'},
 'dataDF': {246: 14843.0,
 247: 14549.9,
 248: 14383.9,
 249: 14340.4,
 250: 14384.1,
 251: 14566.5,
 252: 14681.1,
 253: 14888.6,
 254: 15057.700000000001,
 255: 15230.200000000001,
 256: 15238.4,
 257: 15460.9,
 258: 15587.1,
 259: 15785.299999999999,
 260: 15973.9,
 261: 16121.9,
 262: 16227.9,
 263: 16297.299999999999,
 264: 16475.400000000001,
 265: 16541.400000000001}}
```

Code:

```
 def get_end:
    dataDF = pd.ExcelFile('gdplev.xls').parse(skiprows=7)[['Unnamed: 4', 
'Unnamed: 5']].loc[246:]
    dataDF.columns = ['Quarter','dataDF']
    dataDF['dataDF'] = pd.to_numeric(dataDF['dataDF'])

    def find_end(x):
        qrts = []
        if (dataDF < dataDF.shift()) & (dataDF.shift(periods=1) < 
 dataDF.shift(periods=2)):
            qrts.append(dataDF.shift(2)[0])
        return qrts

    qrts = dataDF.loc[:(len(dataDF) - 2)].apply(find_end)
    return qrts[0]

get_end
```

Error:

```
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in 
    get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       1944             try:
    -> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
       1946             except KeyError:

    pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

    pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
    (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
    (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

    KeyError: 0

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-14-e2cd3908b4c4> in <module>()
         20 
         21 
    ---> 22 get_recession_end()
         23 

    <ipython-input-14-e2cd3908b4c4> in get_recession_end()
         15 
         16     quarters = dataDF.loc[:(len(dataDF) - 2)].apply(do_the_foo)
    ---> 17     return quarters[0]
         18     # return dataDF.head(20).to_dict()
         19 

        /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
        __getitem__(self, key)
           1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
           1996         else:
         -> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
          1998 
       1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
    _getitem_column(self, key)
       2002         # get column
       2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
    -> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
       2005 
       2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
    _get_item_cache(self, item)
           1348         res = cache.get(item)
           1349         if res is None:
        -> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
           1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
           1352             cache[item] = res

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, 
   item, fastpath)
       3288 
       3289             if not isnull(item):
    -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
       3291             else:
       3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))
    [isnull(self.items)]

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in 
    get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
       1946             except KeyError:
    -> 1947                 return 
    self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
       1948 
       1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
    tolerance=tolerance)

    pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

    pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
    (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
    (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

    KeyError: 0
```

Comment: You are getting the error because there is no item at `dataDF.shift(2)[0]`; incidentally, are you sure you mean `&` and not `and` ? They are not the same thing in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The error means pandas could not find column label '0', because df['label'] means accessing columns.

You should use df.loc[0, :] to access row with label 0. If you want to access row at position 0, use df.iloc[0, :].

**Some tips:**

- Alway use .loc[] or .iloc[], do not use [].
- Avoid recursion, use loop instead.